# Finding closest circle from a point

Tags: algorithm, math, language-agnostic, artificial-intelligence, distance

I'm working on my world query methods for finding the closest entity from a point (for AI targeting).  My entities are covered in bounding circles.

I have this:

```
var distanceX : Number = boundingCircle.position.x - startPosition.x;
var distanceY : Number = boundingCircle.position.y - startPosition.y;

var distance : Number = (distanceX * distanceX + distanceY * distanceY);

if (distance < lastDistance)
{
    // set this circle as the closest...
}
```

It doesn't take the radius of the bounding circle in to account though and that's giving me inaccurate results.  Can I just subtract the radius squared from distance to get the distance to the edge of the bounding circle or do I need to calculate a more accurate distance with Math.sqrt?

Thanks!

Comment: shouldn't you be checking that distance < boundingCircle.radius^2 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ***Can I just subtract the radius squared from distance to get the actual distance to the edge of the bounding circle***

Yes, this should be perfectly fine.

If the distance to the enemy is Δ, and his bounding circle radius is *r*, then the distance to his bounding circle is Δ-*r*.

Comment: Fastest question / answer ever?  Cheers :)  (Apparently I have to wait 12 minutes before accepting your answer).

Comment: :-) You're welcome. Btw, can you have an obstacle between your point and the enemy point? I.e., there is not a clear line of sight between you and your enemy, but it *is* a clear line of sight between your point and *some point* within the enemy bounding circle? Or would you simply ignore the case where there is not a clear line of sight between you and the enemy?

Comment: This game ignores those details (as there are no obstacles, heh) so it's not a big deal right now.  Something to consider for future games though!

Answer (score 0):

```
DistanceToCenter - radius == DistanceToCircle
```

but

```
DistanceToCenter^2 - radius^2 != DistanceToCircle^2
```

So you will not get distance by subtraction of squared values...